# Open an existing SQLite database in memory with Lua

Tags: sqlite, lua

The code in my project now:

```
local lsqlite3 = require "lsqlite3complete"
self.db_conn = lsqlite3.open("cost.db")

function showrow(udata,cols,values,names)
     assert(udata=='test_udata')
     for i=1,cols do 
         print('',names[i],values[i])
     end
     return 0
end
self.db_conn:exec('select * from cost',showrow,'test_udata')
```

It is no problem to select the cost records from the code above, but if I change like below and try to open it in memory:

```
self.db_conn = lsqlite3.open_memory("cost.db")
```

The code has no error but there is no records or tables inside when I do the query. How can I change my code so that I can open and put my database inside memory? Since I would like to access my data quickly in memory instead of keep connecting to a database.

Answer (score 0):

A memory database is one that exists only in memory. That is, it doesn't get its data from a file. Because of that, `open_memory` doesn't take any parameters.

If you want to use a database that lives in a file, then that means accessing that file.

You should not need to "keep connecting to a database". You connect to it once at the beginning of the application and keep it open until your application terminates.

Comment: Got it. What if I would like to put all my data from database into memory? I found connecting the database and query it is a bit slow for me, I am finding ways to solve it.

Comment: @appletabo: Stop disconnecting from the database. Leave the connection alone and just do the queries as needed.